# jQuery:how to add opacity to mouse over in fuction

Tags: jquery

looking to add a simple fade in an out on mouseover and out in ths jquery, i tried to add fadeToggle(500) but that doesnt work. any ideas?

```js
$(function(){
$("#test").on("mouseover mouseout", "li", function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).toggle();
 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(function(){
  $("#test").on("mouseover mouseout", "li", function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, I didn't understand very well your question, but I tried something for you, i hope this can help you of some way.

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    teste
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    var img1 = "url('http://goo.gl/OWVWLp')";
    var img2 = "url('http://goo.gl/xtUi1f')";

    $("#test").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", img1).fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $("#test").on("mouseout", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", img2).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#test {
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Here, is the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/7qLpsq12/1/